# How to pass the empty list when doing list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have to create a list with all combination of three multiple lists:

```
a = ['1','2']
b = ['3','4']
c = ['5']

name = []
delimiter = '_'
name = [i + delimiter + j + delimiter + k for i in a for j in b if b for k in c] 

print (name)
['1_3_5', '1_4_5', '2_3_5', '2_4_5']
```

My question is, on some occasions list c is empty.

```
c = []
print (name)
[]
```

Is there a way to prevent it returning as an empty list by altering the list comprehension, **without removing "k in c"**?

Comment: What do you want instead of an empty list? And what's up with that `if b` clause?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extendible method which does not rely on explicit nested `for` loops. For example, using `itertools.product` and `filter`:

```
from itertools import product

a = ['1','2']
b = ['3','4']
c = ['5']

res = ['_'.join(i) for i in product(*filter(None, (a, b, c)))]

# ['1_3_5', '1_4_5', '2_3_5', '2_4_5']
```

With empty `c`:

```
c = []

res = ['_'.join(i) for i in product(*filter(None, (a, b, c)))]

# ['1_3', '1_4', '2_3', '2_4']
```